# Qt5 QSlider color palette no effect under windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, qt5

I use

```
slider->setPalette(QPalette(mycolor, mycolor));
```

to color the slider (Qt5). Under Linux this works perfectly but under Windows 7, the sliders just look completely normal without any change in color.

Is there any way to get colored sliders under windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setAutoFillBackground(true)` on the `QSlider` in order for this to work:

```
QPalette p;
p.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(42, 42, 42));
slider->setAutoFillBackground(true);
slider->setPalette(p);
```

As an alternative, you can use `QSS`:

```
slider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal { background-color: red; } ");
```

for horizontal sliders or

```
slider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:vertical{ background-color: red; } ");
```

for vertical sliders.

If you want to set a `QColor` you would want to do something like:

```
QColor myColor;
myColor.setRgb(42, 42, 42);
QString backgroundColor = QString("rgb("%1, %2, %3);").arg(myColor.red()).arg(myColor.green()).arg(myColor.blue());");
slider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:vertical{ background-color: " + backgroundColor  + " } ");
```

so that the result would be something like:

```
QSlider::groove:vertical{ background-color: rgb(42, 42, 42); }
```

More details [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider).

Comment: Thanks! Can I give a QColor object instead of a string, too? Basically I have three sliders associated to three objects in a 3D-viewport. And to make this association visible, I want to colorize the sliders.

Comment: @Uroc327 See my edits. I haven't tested the code but it should work. If it doesn't let me know and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @luliu is it also possible, to set a 'default' style sheet? Speaking of some equivalent to `->setPalette(QPalette())`

Comment: @Uroc327 Yes, it is possible using `QStyle` but this is a bit more complicated. You need to derive `QStyle`, implement the style for your `QSlider`, which means paint it, and then set the style on your `QWidget` or on the whole `QApplication` if you wish. This provides a better freedom in customizing but it is more tedious and complicated. Here are some details: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/example_of_how_to_style_qtoolbox_with_qstyle

Comment: I've decided to keep my original approach with the Palettes and just enforce the style to Fusion instead of windows style. So the colors I have under linux are also available under Windows

Comment: @luliu I'm not at the computer any more.. Will test it tomorrow

Comment: @lului autoFillBackground seems to be a pretty acceptable workaround. Looks a bit clobby but I guess, it's the best one can achieve with windows.. I'll go with the 'Fusion' style, thanks anyway