# In Qt, how to alpha blend a color into a PixMap or PNG and then use it as the background image in a slider?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a slider:

```
QSlider *mySlider;
```

I wanted to give it a certain appearance, so I added a graphic:

```
mySlider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal {background-image:url(:/main/graphics/mySlider_Background.png);}"
                "QSlider::handle:horizontal {background-image:url(:/main/graphics/mySlider_Handle.png); height:21px; width: 21px;}");
```

Now, it looks like this (the black is the form's background color) (the hatch pattern is actually in mySlider_Background.png)

[image]

**What I'd like to do is alpha blend a color into the background somehow.**

It strikes me that I need to create an alpha mask (probably as a PixMap?) and then blend a single color with the alpha mask pixmap (?) and then set the result as the background to the slider.

I'm not sure how to set the slider's background outside of the stylesheet. 
[Doing something with a QStyle might be the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657818/qt5-qslider-color-palette-no-effect-under-windows), but knowing exactly what part of the style has to be edited appears to be undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background` qss property with a `qlineargradient`:

```
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #B1B1B1, stop:1 #c4c4c4);
```

See the documentation on [Customizing QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider)